# Alter sort and distribution for dependent tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This is the query to change the sort and dist key in Redshift tables.

```
CREATE TABLE new_dummy 
  DISTKEY (id)
  SORTKEY (account_id,created_at)
  AS (SELECT * FROM dummy);

ALTER TABLE dummy RENAME TO old_dummy;
ALTER TABLE new_dummy RENAME TO dummy;
DROP TABLE old_dummy;
```

It throws the below error:

> ERROR:  cannot drop table old_dummy because other objects depend on it
>   HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

So is it not possible to change the keys for dependent tables?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have VIEWs that are referencing the original (`dummy`) table.

When a table is renamed, the VIEW continues to point to the original table, regardless of what it is named. Therefore, trying to delete the table results in an error.

You will need to **drop the view** before dropping the table. You can then **recreate the view** to point to the new `dummy` table.

So, the flow would be:

- Create `new_dummy` and load data
- Drop view
- Drop `dummy`
- Rename `new_dummy` to `dummy`
- Create view

You might think that his is bad, but it's actually a good feature because renaming a table will not break any views. The view will automatically stay with the correct table.

**UPDATE:**

Based on Joe's comment below, the flow would be:

- CREATE VIEW ... WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING

Then, for each reload:

- Create `new_dummy` and load data
- Drop `dummy`
- Rename `new_dummy` to `dummy`

Comment: Note that you can avoid this issue in future by creating the view with the `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` clause. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html

Comment: I don't have any views. But I'd defined some foreign key definitions with other tables.

Comment: Mmm, it's strange that foreign keys are causing these problems, since foreign keys are not enforced in Redshift (but they are used to optimize queries). In that case, renaming tables will not assist.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon the fact that you have foreign key references within the table definition, which are not compatible with the process of renaming and dropping tables.

Given this situation, I would recommend that you load data as follows:

- Start a transaction
- `DELETE *` from the table
- Load data with `INSERT INTO`
- End the transaction

This means you are totally reloading the contents of the table. Wrapping it in a transaction means that there is no period where the table will appear 'empty'.

However, this leaves the table in a bit of a messy state, requiring a `VACUUM` to delete the old data.

Alternatively, you could:

- `TRUNCATE` the table
- Load data with `INSERT INTO`

`TRUNCATE` does not require a cleanup since it clears all data associated with the table (not just marking it for deletion). However, TRUNCATE immediately commits the transaction, so there will be a gap where the table will be empty.